# Overlapping Toastbar messages

Tags: codenameone

I'm using the ToastBar messages with timeout 6 seconds. If I click another button within 6 seconds which will display another toastbar message, second one will overlap with first one in some instances. How can a dispose first message and display second message without overlapping if the button is clicked before timeout occurs. Please advise.

ToastBar.showErrorMessage("Test Message", 6000);

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are always invoking this method from the EDT and not from a separate thread e.g. the network thread. Use the edt error detection tool in the simulator to try and track such issues.

Comment: I'm doing it the same way still I see messages overlap. Is there a way I force the previous message dispose and show second message in this situation.Please advise.

Comment: show returns a status object which you can `clear()`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. First I tried to make sure that I do not call each message using the same object reference, but also use local variable instances to allow the Garbage Collector (GC) dispose them since the instance is discarded when the task is done.

However, this may take some time and the message still appears overlapping or even worse, it repeats itself with out a trigger, but less likely (infrequent) now because the GC collects the object.

It may be tempting to call the GC manually if possible, but then you need to assess performance impact.

I have not attempted yet the approach I am about to suggest, but let me know what you think.
Making it so, that `ToastBar` messages appear one on top of the other when triggered. Maybe a `List<ToastBar>` object or other similar may prove useful. This may be described as a `ToastBar` "buffer".

The other way around is to `clear()` the message but then if it is too long it will not allow the user the necessary time to read the feedback.

I have this in my TODO list but will follow up when I make some additional progress.